# Windows 7 access control explained

Tags: windows-7, uac

I'm getting a little confused with Windows 7 access control.

I'm aware of why access control is in Windows 7, and I'm relatively familiar with Linux access control. Does Windows 7 access control work in a similar way (i.e. changing the ownership of particular file/directory)?

Can anybody point me in the direction of a good guide to Windows 7 access control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the UAC works by borrowing ownership from the Admin To help prevent malicious software from silently installing and causing computer-wide infection. UAC is similar to Linux Sudo.

Hopefully this guide will help.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx